# PHP foreach subarray in array

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to parse an array that looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement"] => array(412) {
    [0] => array(5) {
      ["CodeDepartement"] => string(8) "DEPBRAND"
      ["NummerHoofdstrategischeDoelstelling"] => string(1) "1"
      ["Nummer"] => string(2) "27"
      ["Titel"] => string(22) "DSD 01 - HULPVERLENING"
      ["IdBudgetronde"] => string(1) "2"
    }
    [1] => array(5) {
      ["CodeDepartement"] => string(8) "DEPBRAND"
      ["NummerHoofdstrategischeDoelstelling"] => string(1) "2"
      ["Nummer"] => string(2) "28"
      ["Titel"] => string(24) "DSD 02 - Dienstverlening"
      ["IdBudgetronde"] => string(1) "2"
    }
    [2] => array(5) {
      ["CodeDepartement"] => string(8) "DEPBRAND"
      ["NummerHoofdstrategischeDoelstelling"] => string(1) "2"
      ["Nummer"] => string(2) "29"
      ["Titel"] => string(16) "DSD 03 - KLANTEN"
      ["IdBudgetronde"] => string(1) "2"
    }
    ...
```

(The array goes on but it's too big to post it here in its entirety)

I can do a foreach loop on the array like this:

```
foreach($my_arr->StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement as $row){
    echo "i found one <br>";
}
```

However, I want to do the same thing on other arrays and I want to make the function generic. The first key (StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement in this case) can sometimes change, which is why I'd like to do it generically. I've already tried the following:

```
foreach($my_arr[0] as $row){
    echo "i found one <br>";
}
```

But then I get the following notice, and no data:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\GitHub\Backstage\application\controllers\AdminController.php on line 29
```

This is probably a silly question, but I'm new to PHP and this seemed like the right way to do it. Obviously, it isn't. Can anyone help me out, please?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) to grab the first element of `$my_arr` without knowing the key name:

```
$a = reset($my_arr);
foreach($a as $row){
    echo "i found one <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do is object, not array `$my_arr->StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement`.
You could use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check the index existence:

```
if(isset($my_arr['StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement'])){
    foreach($my_arr['StrategischeDoelstellingenPerDepartement'] as $row){
        echo "i found one <br>";
    }
}
```

Or, you could use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to ignore the array keys and to make it an index array:

```
$my_new_arr = array_values($my_arr);
foreach($my_new_arr as $row){
    echo "i found one <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift the sub-array off the main array and loop over it:

```
$sub = array_shift($my_arr);
foreach ($sub as $row) {
    echo $row['Titel'], "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `current` ref : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

```
$a = current($my_arr);
foreach($a as $row){
    echo "i found one <br>";
}
```